# mysql добавляются НЕ все элементы в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Написал парсер

Есть несколько проблем

1. Добавляются в базу не все фильмы (на экран выводятся все 40, а в базу попадают 14)
2. Не все переменные записываются в базу 
   $title, $desc, $stream_url в базу попадают, остальные типа $imdb, $regiser не попадают`

   ```
           header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type");
           if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS') exit;

           require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
           set_time_limit(0);

           function get_result($url) {
               $curl = curl_init();
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
               // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
               $res = curl_exec($curl);
               return $res;
           }

           echo '<items>';

           function parser_simple_html($url, $i) {
               if($i < 1) {
                   $file = str_get_html(get_result($url));
                   $courses = $file->find('.movie-title, 0');

                   foreach($courses as $article) {
                       $one = str_get_html(get_result($article->href));
                       $one_dom = str_get_html($one);
                       $title = $one_dom->find('h1', 0)->plaintext; // Название
                       $kach = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 0)->plaintext; // Якість
                       $god = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 1)->plaintext; // Рік виходу
                       $strana = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 2)->plaintext; // Країна
                       $genre = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 3)->plaintext; // Жанр
               // Обрезаем до 45 символов
                       $genre = mb_strimwidth("$genre", 0, 45, "...");
                       $regiser = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 4)->plaintext; // Режисер
                       $actor = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 5)->plaintext; // Актори
               // Обрезаем до 90 символов
                       $actor = mb_strimwidth("$actor", 0, 90, "...");
                       $mova = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 7)->plaintext; // Мова озвучення
                       $mova = str_replace('Український дубляж', "<span style='color:#159ff6'>Український дубляж</span>", $mova);
                       $date = $one_dom->find('.mov-date', 0)->plaintext;
                       $logo = $one_dom->find('img[itemprop=image]', 0)->src;
                       $levoe = $one_dom->find('.film-info', 0)->plaintext;
                       $stream_url = $one_dom->find('iframe', 0)->src;

                       $imdb = $one_dom->find('.fi-desc', 8)->plaintext;
                       $desc = $one_dom->find('.full-text', -2)->plaintext;
                       // $desc = "<span style='color:#FF6347'>$desc</span>";

                       // Удалить все после слеша
                       $imdb = explode('/', $imdb);
                       $imdb = $imdb[0];
                       $imdb = "<span style='color:#FF6347'>$imdb</span>";

                       echo "<channel>";
                       echo "<title>$title ($god)</title>";
                       echo "<stream_url><![CDATA[$stream_url</stream_url>";
                       echo "<logo_30x30><![CDATA[https://uakino.club$logo</logo_30x30>";
                       echo "<description><p><img src=https://uakino.club$logo height=228px; width=152px; align=left vspace=10 hspace=10><img src=https://uakino.club/templates/uakino/images/imdb-mini.png>&nbsp; $imdb<h5>Якість: $kach<br>Рік виходу: $god<br>Країна: $strana<br>Жанр: $genre<br>Режисер: $regiser<br>Актори: $actor<br><br>$mova<br><p>$desc</p></h5></description>";
                       echo "</channel>\n";

                       $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
                       $success = $mysqli->query("REPLACE INTO uakino (`title`, `desc`, `stream_url`, `logo_30x30`, `regiser`) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$stream_url', 'https://uakino.club$logo', '$regiser')");
                       echo $success;
                       $mysqli->close();

                       // break;
                   }
                   if (isset($file->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href) && !empty($file->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href));
                       $href = $file->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href;
                       // echo $href;
                       $i++;
                       parser_simple_html($href,$i);
               }
           }
           $i = 0;
           parser_simple_html('https://uakino.club/film/',$i);

           echo '</items>';
   ```

Ума не приложу где ошибки

Comment: Открывать и закрывать соединение в бд в цикле не надо - откройте один раз в начале и закройте в конце цикла. Запрос подвержен sql инъекции. Используйте подготовленные запросы. Что касается вашего вопроса: тут надо проверить - сколько реально запросов пошло в бд. Если те же 40, значит что-то с запросами. Запросто может быть что данные что вы пытаетесь вставить содержать кавычки и это ломает запрос. Включите вывод ошибок, ну и используйте подготовленные запросы.

Comment: что-то говорить об sql инъекции при написании парсера не особо уместно.

Comment: Убрал из записи в базу $desc, стало записывать 36 фильмов из 40